# Katakana vs Hiragana

Tags: katakana, hiragana

So I'm playing Pokemon Alpha Sapphire in Japanese hiragana (no kanji) to help with my reading comprehension. I've been noticing some of the characters will use words that I normally see in hiragana (like きみ) in katakana.

The question is why some of the words are being used in both hiragana and katakana. So far, most sources I've seen say that katakana is used for names and foreign words, so I'm confused on why I'll sometimes see the typical Japanese word in katakana instead of hiragana. Is it common for the katakana spelling to replace a typical hiragana spelling? Additionally, what exactly is changing when the typical hiragana word is written in katakana?

Comment: Thanks for the link! It didn't answer my answer specifically but it gave me enough information to understand in relation to my question.

Comment: In your case, is it possible to name characters who use katakana often? It could be characterization or could be game-wide style.